# How to get back serialized data that was sent with jquery $_post in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would simply like to know how do i retrieve this data back in php? (it is serialized and in JSON)

This is my current code:

relevant html bit:

```
<form id="add-review-form" action="/review/save" method="post">
       <div>
            <textarea name="reviewDescription" class="review"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="organisationId" value="<?=$this->organisation->id?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="score"/>
            <button id="save-review-button" type="button" class="small">Opslaan</button>

        </div>

</form>
```

Jquery bit:

```
            // Get form as jQuery object
            var addReviewForm = $('#add-review-form');

            // Remove errors
            removeFormMessages( addReviewForm );

            // Get data
            var data = addReviewForm.serialize();
            $.post("/review/save", data, function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
           ,"json" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call JQuery post this way:

```
$.post("/review/save", {json: JSON.stringify(data)}, 
      function (data, status) {
         console.log(data);
      }, "json" );
```

Later on PHP side you can access submited json object after parsing it:

```
<?php
   $json_array = json_decode($_POST['json']);
?>
```

Comment: then this will be accesible like an array? for example $jsondata['score'] would give me the score?(i am not very familiar with json)

Comment: exactly. On the other hand if you made a post the way you did in question, you could access submited values as normal POST parameters, like $_POST['INPUT_VALUE_NAME']

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw data like

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

To get the json data from this you can use

```
$jsondata = json_decode($rawdata,true);
```

If the second parameter is true, `json_decode` will return the result in `associative` array

Comment: then this will be accesible like an array? for example  $jsondata['score'] would give me the score?(i am not very familiar with json)

Comment: i have updated the answer as per your requirement. if you pass second parameter as `true` in `json_decode` it will return associative array so that you can use like `$jsondata['score']`. For more info try `var_dump($jsondata)` in php code.